# Codeigniter ajax function not redirecting to login page if session does not exists

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter for my web application which is having user registration feature. And also i am using ajax in most of the places for loading the page. The problem is, if some function is called through ajax to load a page and if session does not exists, it is not redirecting to the login page. But it is working when we visits the same URL through browser(It is redirecting to the login page). What should i do to resolve this problem?

This is the code for checking session we are using.

```
    $userid=$this->phpsession->get('userid');
    if(!($userid))
    { 
        redirect('home','refresh');
    }
```

Comment: please post the ajax code, and the login controller.

Comment: ajax will not execute the redirect('home','refresh');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller detect if it is an ajax request:

```
if($this->input->is_ajax_request())
{
    $userid=$this->phpsession->get('userid');
    if(!($this->usermodel->is_user($userid)))
    { 
        echo "1";
    }
}
```

In ajax detect the response and redirect to the login page:

```
$.post('index.php/login', function(data){

if(data == "1")
{
document.location.href = <?php echo site_url("home"); ?>;
}

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Adam. I will check out this.

Comment: This is a bad idea. If the person disables javascript it won't redirect them.

Comment: @Mike I'm suggesting to add the ajax code to the controller not delete the old code.

Comment: But if i include the code suggested above , it is showing this error `Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Input::is_ajax_request() in /var/www/panhive/system/application/controllers/stores.php`

Comment: The function is in codeigniter 2. Please see: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/59450/

Comment: OK Thanks Adam. I am using CI version 1.7.3. And i got that function from CI 2.0 version. Thanks.