# Session create by ajax but destroyed when page refresh in codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter-3, php-5.5

I have create session using ajax in a page but it destroyed when i refresh that page in codeigniter. When i print this session data it will return null.

controler code for create session(through ajax)

```
public function check_database() {
    $username =$this->input->post('username');
    $password =$this->input->post('password');
    $result = $this->Api_model->login($username, $password);
    if ($result) {
    $sess_array = array();
    foreach ($result as $data) { 
    $sess_array = array( 'id' => $data->id, 'username' => $data->user_name, 
    'type' =>$data->type, 'email' => $data->email, 'phone' => $data->mobile 
     );
    $this->session->set_userdata('admin_logged_in', $sess_array);
    }
    $session_data = $this->session->userdata('admin_logged_in');
    print_r(Json_encode($session_data));
    } else {
    echo 0;
    } }

 session check method

 function ourservice() {
    $session_data = $this->session->userdata('admin_logged_in');
    $ids = $session_data['id'];
    $this->load->view('our_service');
  }
```

---

After create session by ajax call, i will check session by ajax call also and it retun session value,but when i refresh my codeigniter page and check session on page load event it will return null also if i check session in another function in controller it also return null.

Comment: Is the ajax page using codeigniter as well or your own code? If its your own you'll probably be using a different session ID - have a look and see what cookies you have. If it is a codeigniter page then that should be ok - so perhaps post some examples of your code.

Comment: yes my ajax code is in codeigniter page.I have write my ajax code in a separate js file and include in my codeigniter page. i have post my code above.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10600692/codeigniter-ajax-function-not-redirecting-to-login-page-if-session-does-not-exis?rq=1